# SCSS for loop generate

Tags: css, sass

I want to generate nthchild with sass

and have a problem

```
@for $i from 0 through 10 {
  div {
    content: $i + 1;
  }
}
```

It generate this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10;

I need this result: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

Any ideas?

Comment: $i + 2? this generate 2,3,4,5,6,7,8.... i tryed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  div {
    content: $i * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but if i want to generate this: element:nth-child(#{$i}*2) { //some s tyle }, it will be err.

Comment: Use element:nth-child(#{$i*2}) { //some s tyle }, you have put *2 outside {} block, that will give you an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can add @if condition inside @for.

Below is scss code :

```
@for $i from 0 through 10 {
  @if $i % 2 == 0 and $i != 0 {
    div {
      content: $i;
    } 
  }
}
```

Above scss code generates below css code :

```
div {
  content: 2;
}

div {
  content: 4;
}

div {
  content: 6;
}

div {
  content: 8;
}

div {
  content: 10;
}
```

Comment: And how can i generete inside @if statement this div:nth-child(2,4,6..) { style: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }? \

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, if you want div:nth-child(2,4,6...) then change `div` to `div:nth-child(#{$i})`. I don't understand { style: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} part, can you explain it?

Comment: i have variable $i with value 2,4,6,8,10 inside if statement yeah? and want another variable inside @if which value will be 1,2,3,4,5.... and how?